# Dual space of the space of matrix-valued, continuous functions on a locally-compact, Hausdorff space vanishing at infinity.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, duality-theorems

Let $X$ be a locally-compact, Hausdorff space, and let $\mathcal{A}:=C_{0}(X)$ the $C^{*}$-algebra of complex-valued, continuous functions vanishing at infinity.
Let $\mathcal{B}:=M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ the $C^{*}$-algebra of $n\times n$ complex matrices.
The tensor product $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B}$ is well-defined as a $C^{*}$-algebra and it is isomorphic to $C_{0}(X,\mathcal{B})$ (see for instance thm: II.9.4.4 in Blackadar's book).

Since the dual space $\mathcal{A}'$ of $\mathcal{A}$ may be identified with the space of complex-valued Radon measures on $X$, and the dual space $\mathcal{B}'$ may be identified with $\mathcal{B}$ itself, I was wondering if it is possible to identify the dual space $(\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B})'\cong(C_{0}(X,\mathcal{B}))'$ with the space of $\mathcal{B}$-valued Radon measures on $X$, and thus the space of states of $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}$ with the space of $S$-valued Radon measures on $X$, where $S$ is the space of positive semidefinite matrices with unit trace.

Since it is just a mere curiosity triggered by a casual conversation I had yesterday, I did not yet really try to prove anything, but I have the impression that this could be a well-known result for experts in $C^{*}$-algebra theory.

Comment: Does the answer provided also prove the conjecture you posed about the state space of $\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$?

Comment: @Ramanujan, I think it does because if you consider elements of the type $\mathbf{x}\otimes\chi_{A}$ with $\mathbf{x}$ positive in $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\chi_{A}$ a characteristic function on $X$, you can check that the dual pairing forces every positive linear functional to be a positive measure with values in positive matrices, and then the converse should follow from direct computation. However, I do not have a rigorous proof. At the time I was thinking about this problem it felt true and that was enough for me :-)

Comment: Of course you can ask! I tend to be interested in the differential geometry of (suitable subsets of) the space of states/positive linear functionals of C*/W*/Jordan algebras, essentially because of my interest in the so-called field of Information Geometry. Therefore, I have to deal with functional-analytic things even if "I am not academically trained" for these things. I bounce back the question to you :-)

Comment: Note: in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4622142/545914) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4622312/545914) it is stated that the state space can be identified with the symmetric positive semidefinite matrix-valued measures $u$ with $\text{tr}(u(X)) = 1$, which is different from your conjecture.

Comment: My interest stems from understanding how the Connes metric on state space looks like for matrix-valued measures.

Comment: I think what explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4622142/545914) is exactly what I conjectured. Perhaps, the way I wrote it ($S$-valued Radon measure on $X$ where $S$ is the space of positive semidefinite matrices with unit trace) was ambiguous but I meant exactly what written there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that if $A$ is any $C^*$-algebra, then $M_n(A)^*$ is isomorphic to $M_n(A^*)$. In your case, if $R_X$ denotes the space of Radon measures on $X$
\begin{align}
C_0\big(X,M_n(\mathbb C)\big)^*
& \cong (A\otimes B)^*
= \big(C_0(X)\otimes M_n(\mathbb C)\big)^* \\
& = M_n(C_0(X))^*
\cong M_n(C_0(X)^*)
\cong M_n(R_X).
\end{align}
Now I am no expert in measure theory but I don't feel confident about matrices with measure-entries being the same as measures with matrix values. That's only my guess though.

As requested: let $\zeta_{i,j}:A\to M_n(A)$ denote the map $\zeta_{i,j}(a)=a\otimes e_{i,j}$, where $e_{k,l}$ are matrix units (i.e. $a\otimes e_{i,j}$ is the matrix with $0$'s everywhere and $a$ in the i,j slot). This is easily seen to be a linear isometry. Define $T:M_n(A)^*\to M_n(A^*)$ by $T(\varphi)=[\zeta_{i,j}^*(\varphi)]_{i,j}\equiv[\varphi\circ\zeta_{i,j}]_{i,j}$. This is easily seen to be a vector space isomorphism. This is for example demonstrated in [C. Lance's paper "On nuclear $C^*$-algebras" (1973)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123673900219), but the details are easy to fill in.

Comment: thank you for the details. I thought a little bit more about the issue "matrix-valued measures VS matrix of measures", and I somehow changed idea. I think they are the same because a matrix-valued measure gives you as much measures as there are entries in the matrix, and from these measures you can build a matrix of measures, and "viceversa". However, I do not have a rigorous proof.

Comment: @Ittiolo well, if that's true I am pretty sure that the details will be easy to work out